# How to configure SQL Server to manage ASP.NET sessions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I need to know how to configure the .config to manage Session state in SQL Server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to create a Session database. In order to do this:

1. Look for the aspnet_regsql.exe
2. Run this command aspnet_regsql.exe -S [ServerName] -E -ssadd -sstype p

Where ServerName is your server name.

This will create this database ASPState

Now the configuration on the web.config

Add this sentence over

```
<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="false" mode="SQLServer" sqlCommandTimeout="7200" sqlConnectionString="Server=SERVERNAME;User ID=User;Password=Password;" timeout="120" />
```

sqlCommandTimeout="7200" = 2hours and  timeout="120" = 2hours

If you need more options regarding aspnet_regsql you can take a look  [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
<configuration>
  <sessionstate 
      mode="stateserver"
      cookieless="false" 
      timeout="20" 
      sqlconnectionstring="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<user id>;password=<password>"
      server="127.0.0.1" 
      port="42424" 
  />
</configuration>
```

Additional options here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Comment: I think that should be mode="SQLServer"?