# SQL Server Storing session state seems not to be working?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I've configured SQL Server to store session state ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880824/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-manage-asp-net-sessions/4880876#4880876)).

All I want to do is that when the user has logged into my application via browser A, I see that logged session when I visit my app from the browser B.

Right now that scenario doesn't work, I must log in one more time.

Comment: That's not the purpose of the SQL Server session state - it allows multiple web servers to service the same user. If you want multiple browser sessions to share the same "session", that's something you'll have to build.

Answer (score 2):

When browser B is opened (assuming it's a different browser altogether or a new instance of the same browser) a new session is created; therefore, what you see is expected behavior.

Also, I assume you mention this because you store in session some sort of key that indicates that the user has logged in successfully, correct?

If you want this behavior, you'd need to send some sort of authentication cookie with a long expiration date, you'd then read the cookie on the login page and consider the user as successfully authenticated, but keep in mind that this is a potential security risk.

Comment: @Tony: To expand a bit: Session is **not** per *user* or per *machine*; it's per browser instance.