# Session data disappears when using SQLServer session mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I have very strange problem with session data. *Problem doesn't appear when using InProc session mode.*
This is how it happens:
1. `HttpContext.Current.Session["testparam"] = "string value";`
2. I check for this data in `Page.Unload` event. Data is still there.
3. After another request is initiated I can't fetch data in `Page.OnInit` although I didn't delete it.

Additional facts:
There aren't any serialization errors in log.
Session database is created using this [procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880824/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-manage-asp-net-sessions).
Error appears in both IIS and ASP.NET development server.
I tried both SQLServer mode and AppFabric distributed cache mode.

Any help is appreciated since I'm out of ideas.

Comment: can you post the error .. as well as the code where you are assigning the HttpContext.Current.Session var also Onload and onInit code may be helpful..do you have anything like Global.asax page ..?

Comment: There isn't any error, session variable is set to null in second request (I looked in session EntriesTable). I have global.asax but I don't set session variable values in it.

Comment: My bad. Don't know how, but I missed obvious serialization exception at the end of output window. I suppose that application kept working because exception occurred during callback.

Comment: Have you tried fetching the data on Page_Load instead of init?

Answer (score 1):

Check if **EnableSessionState** is set to false in the page directive of the second page. If it is set to false, the value will not be fetched from SQL on page load. Whereas, this will not happen in InProc mode.

Comment: I don't use EnableSessionState in any of pages.