# SQL Server to manage ASP.NET sessions doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2, session-state

I follow the direction in here [How to configure SQL Server to manage ASP.NET sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880824/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-manage-asp-net-sessions) to create ASPState db. 
I have 2 web application in IIS 7. In IIS web application setting, i go to "Session State" and set session state as "SQL Server" and provide connection string. 
In each web application web.config, i add

```
<sessionState
       mode="SQLServer"
       allowCustomSqlDatabase="false"
       sqlConnectionString="data source=server;user id=user;password=password"
       cookieless="false"
       timeout="7200"
/>
```

I create a session ,

```
Session["Data"] = "test"
```

in Web App A and go to Web App B in the same browser to print it

```
Response.Write(Session["Data"]);
```

It shows NOTHING. I can see there are data in table : ASPStateTempApplications and ASPStateTempSessions under ASPState Database. Also, i dont see any error in event log. Can anyone think anything i may do wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: do you access both applications with the same domain name?

Comment: Yes, it is at localhost. It is http://localhost:8080/WebApp_A and http://localhost:8080/WebApp_B

Comment: @windforceus Now understand, you try from app A to get it on app B. This is impossible !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can not get session that belongs to App-A from App-B and vice versa.
```

The sessions are connected with the cookies, and the cookies are different between app-a and app-b, are random made. Even if set some how the same cookies then next the database connects session with the Application ID, that are also different for each applications.

So even if you have the same database, the application id is different, and the cookies are different, and you can not get session from a to b.

The only possible way to archive that is to make your custom session code, and some how knows that you have the same use on app-A and app-B, so to connected them together.

Comment: Hi Aritos, do you need to configure the IIS Setting for the web application? Do i need to do this step -> ( In IIS, go to the web application setting,  go to "Session State" and set session state as "SQL Server" and provide connection string.)

Comment: I does those and still not get the data. I can see the expires date changs in ASPStateTempSessions table when i browse the web page but i couldn't get the Session Data.

Comment: Hi Aristos, sounds tricky. So there is no good way for multiple web applications share same session in the same server? The reason i use Session State is trying to have multiple web applications to share same session such as login in Web A and continue to browse in Web B without login.

Comment: @windforceus Only if you make it custom. You make a custom database, and some how you connect the cookie of the user with the data. Next you find a way to connect the same cookies on two different apps, maybe with the user logon or something like that. Needs a little design. By default session have many security steps to avoid to do that. Thinks that if they let do that, in a share environment it will be possible to read the sessions data from the rest users.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, i mark this is the answer, sux i waste 2 days and realize this is impossible.

Comment: @windforceus I have pass the same :) now I have made totally custom session ! :)

Comment: sounds like a cool idea, it will be over kill for what i need to do. I would probably spend time on other requirements to catch deadline.